# Checking for the files if it is present in other folder or not

Tags: java, file

I have a scenario where there are two different folders with 2000 and 1000 files in them .. I need to compare that whether the files present in 1000 files folder are also present in the other folder? How to find it using java..? If any one has the code can you please share ..

Comment: Create two ordered lists (files of each folder) and compare them (see java.util.List for methods of intersection)

Answer (score 0):

I set here some pseudo code.

Go to folder1 and save the name of all files into a Map

```
while(haveFiles) {
    folder1Map.put(file.getName(), file.getName())
}
```

Do the same with the folder 2

```
while(haveFiles) {
    folder2Map.put(file.getName(), file.getName())
}
```

Now you can do a loop for the folder with the 1000 files and check that every file is in the second Map.

```
while(folder1Map.hasKeys()) {
    if(!folder2Map.contains(key)){
         //The folder with 2000 files doesnt contains all files of folder 1
    }
}
```